# Simd matmul program gives different numerical results

Tags: c, floating-point, vectorization, simd, avx

I am trying to program the matrix multiplication in C using simd intrinsics. I was pretty sure of my implementation, but when I execute, i get some numerical errors starting from the 5th digit of the resulting matrix's coefficients.

REAL_T is just a float with typedef

```
/* This is my matmul Version with simd, using floating simple precision*/
void matmul(int n, REAL_T *A, REAL_T *B, REAL_T *C){
  int i,j,k;
  __m256 vA, vB, vC, vRes;
  for (i=0; i<n; i++){
    for (j=0; j<n; j++){  
      for (k=0; k<n; k= k+8){
        vA = _mm256_load_ps(&A[i*n+k]);
        vB = _mm256_loadu_ps(&B[k*n+j]);
        vC = _mm256_mul_ps(vA, vB);
        vC = _mm256_hadd_ps(vC, vC);
        vC = _mm256_hadd_ps(vC, vC);
        /*To get the resulting coefficient, after doing 2 hadds,
        I have to get the first and the last element of the resulting
        Vector vC*/
        C[i*n+j] += ((float )(vC[0])) + ((float )(vC[7]));
      } /* for k */
    } /* for j */
  } /* for i */
}
*/End of program
```

```
/*And this is the sequential Version*/
void matmul(int n, REAL_T *A, REAL_T *B, REAL_T *C){
  int i,j,k;
  for (i=0; i<n; i++){ 
    for (j=0; j<n; j++){
      for (k=0; k<n; k++){
        C[i*n+j] +=  A[i*n+k] *  B[k*n+j];  
      } /* for k */
    } /* for j */
  } /* for i */  
}
/*End of program*/
```

```
/*The matrix are initialized as follows*/
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    for (j = 0; j < n; j++){
      *(A+i*n+j) = 1 / ((REAL_T) (i+j+1));
      *(B+i*n+j) = 1.0;
      *(C+i*n+j) = 1.0;
    }
/*End of initialization*/
```

The tested matrix are of size 512*512.
For the sequential version, the top left square of the resulting matrix gives:

```
+6.916512e+01  +6.916512e+01  
+5.918460e+01  +5.918460e+01  

+7.946186e+00  +7.946186e+00  
+7.936391e+00  +7.936391e+00
```

However, for the simd version, the square is:

```
+6.916510e+01  +6.916510e+01  
+5.918463e+01  +5.918463e+01  

+7.946147e+00  +7.946147e+00  
+7.936355e+00  +7.936355e+00
```

There is as shown a numerical error between the 2 versions.
Any help would be really appreciated !

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This looks normal; adding numbers in a different order produces different rounding in the temporaries.

**FP math is not associative; optimizing as if it is will change the results.**<sup>1</sup>  [Is Floating point addition and multiplication associative?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10371857/is-floating-point-addition-and-multiplication-associative)  /  [Are floating point operations in C associative?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13913017/are-floating-point-operations-in-c-associative)

The amount of change depends on the data.  Differences only in the 5th decimal place seems reasonable for `float`.

---

**Unless you were taking special numerical precautions like adding up the small numbers first, the sequential-order result isn't "more correct", they just have different errors.**

In fact, **using multiple accumulators generally *increases* precision** for large lists, assuming your numbers all have similar magnitude.   (Ideally multiple SIMD vectors each composed of multiple elements, to hide FP-add or FMA latency). 
 **https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairwise_summation** is a numerical technique that takes this to the next level: summing subsets of the list in a tree, to avoid adding single array elements to a much larger value.  See for example, [How to avoid less precise sum for numpy-arrays with multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55512278/how-to-avoid-less-precise-sum-for-numpy-arrays-with-multiple-columns)

Using a fixed number of accumulators (e.g. 8x `__m256` = 64 `float` accumulators) might reduce expected error by a factor of 64, instead of from N to log N for full pairwise summation.

---

Footnote 1: **Associativity is necessary for parallelization, and SIMD, and multiple accumulators.**  [Associativity gives us parallelizability. But what does commutativity give?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35443424/associativity-gives-us-parallelizability-but-what-does-commutativity-give)

On a machine with for example 4-cycle latency 2-per-clock throughput FMA, with a SIMD width of 8 floats, i.e. a Skylake system with AVX2, the potential speedup is 4*2 = 8 from multiple accumulators, * 8 from SIMD width, times number of cores, vs. a pure sequential version, even for problems where it *might* be less accurate instead of just different.

Most people consider a factor of `8*8 = 64` worth it!  (And you can in theory also parallelize for another factor of maybe 4 on a quad-core, assuming perfect scaling for large matrices).

You're already using `float` instead of `double` for performance.

See also [Why does mulss take only 3 cycles on Haswell, different from Agner's instruction tables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45113527/why-does-mulss-take-only-3-cycles-on-haswell-different-from-agners-instruction) for more about using multiple accumulators to hide FMA latency in a reduction, exposing that other factor of 8 speedup.

Also, do *not* use `hadd` inside an inner-most loop.  Sum vertically, and use an efficient reduction at the end of the loop.  ([Fastest way to do horizontal float vector sum on x86](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6996764/fastest-way-to-do-horizontal-float-vector-sum-on-x86)).  You really really want to avoid having the compiler extract your vectors to scalar at every step, that defeats most of the benefit of SIMD!  Besides the fact that `hadd` is not worth using for horizontal sums of 1 vector; it costs 2 shuffles + a regular `add` on all existing CPUs.

Comment: Also related: [Efficient stable sum of a sorted array in AVX2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46119811)