# Fortran code compiled in one Windows machine (2018 Intel processor) gives different results when exe is copied to other machine (2022 Intel processor)

Tags: floating-point, fortran, intel, intel-fortran, fast-math

Is it possible that a Fortran code compiled in one Windows machine with Visual studio 2019 on a 2018 Intel processor gives a slightly different result when the exe is copied to another machine (that has a 2022 Intel processor)? Could you please list the possible causes of this behavior?

Answer (score 8):

Run-time dispatch to different versions of functions based on CPU instruction sets, and/or auto-parallelization to all cores, are likely candidates.

Some compiler optimizations pretend that FP math is associative.  In reality, FP math is not quite associative; different temporaries introduces different rounding error.

**Different choices in how to find parallelism** (like auto-vectorization) in loops like a dot-product or sum of an array can lead to different rounding, which can make the result numerically more accurate, but different from the source order of operations<sup>1</sup>.  Such loops can only be vectorized by pretending FP math is associative.

---

**Auto-parallelization** (e.g. OpenMP) with a **different number of cores** could break a problem up in a different way, into different sub-totals.  If your program uses all cores, that's a likely candidate.

Intel compilers can also make code that **dispatches to different versions of a function depending on which SIMD instruction sets are available**.  So you could have an SSE4 version, an AVX2+FMA version, and an AVX-512 version (perhaps even using 512-bit vectors.)

Different SIMD widths lead to a different number of accumulators, if the loop uses the same number of vector registers.  So that's a different sets of numbers getting added together into subtotals, e.g. for a dot product.

Does only one of the processors have AVX-512?  Or is one of them a Pentium or Celeron without AVX?  If so, that's also a likely factor.

Runtime-dispatch in library functions like TBB or SVML could also be a factor, not just code directly generated by the compiler.

---

#### Intel compiler FP-math options

Intel compilers default to `-fp-model=fast`.  See the docs for [Intel Fortran](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/fortran-compiler-oneapi-dev-guide-and-reference/top/compiler-reference/floating-point-operations/use-the-fp-model-fp-option.html) and [Intel C/C++ compiler](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/cpp-compiler-developer-guide-and-reference/top/compiler-reference/compiler-options/floating-point-options/fp-model-fp.html) (both classic, not LLVM-based OneAPI, although presumably they turn on `-ffast-math` by default in that).  The C++ compiler docs seem more detailed in their descriptions.

(The other mainstream compilers, like LLVM and GCC (`gfortran`), default to `-fno-fast-math`.  But if you use OpenMP, you can let the compiler treat the sum or product or whatever in a specific reduction loop as associative.)

Specifically the Intel  default is `fast=1`, and there's an even more aggressive level of optimization, `-fp-model=fast=2` that's not on by default.

**See also Intel's 2018 article [Consistency of Floating-Point Results using the Intel® Compiler
or
Why doesn’t my application always give the same answer?](https://www.intel.com/content/dam/develop/external/us/en/documents/pdf/fp-consistency-121918.pdf)**, covering the kinds of value-unsafe optimization Intel's compilers do and how the various FP-model switches affect that.   And/or slides from a [2008 talk](https://www.nccs.nasa.gov/images/FloatingPoint_consistency.pdf) of the same title.

Quoting some descriptions from that article:

- `-fp-model=consistent` - not necessarily the same order of operations as the source, but the same on every machine.  And run-to-run consistency when auto-parallelizing with OpenMP.  Otherwise with dynamic scheduling of a reduction, the way subtotals are added could depend on which threads finished which work first.
- `-fp-model=precise`  - allows value-safe optimizations only (but still including contraction of `a*b+c` into an FMA).
- `-fp-model=strict` - enables access to the FPU environment (e.g. you can change the FP rounding mode and compiler optimizations will respect that possibilitiy).
  disables floating-point contractions
  such as fused multiply-add (fma) instructions
  implies “precise” and “except

This part probably doesn't lead to optimizations that vary across machines, but it interesting:

> The ANSI Fortran standard is less restrictive than the C standard: it requires the
> compiler to respect the order of evaluation specified by parentheses, but
> otherwise allows the compiler to reorder expressions as it sees fit. The Intel
> Fortran compiler has therefore implemented a corresponding switch,
> /assume:protect_parens (-assume protect_parens), that results in standardconforming behavior for reassociation, with considerably less impact on
> performance than /fp:precise (-fp-model precise). This switch does not affect
> any value-unsafe optimizations other than reassociation.

---

#### Footnote 1: different isn't always worse, numerically

Floating point math always has rounding error (except in rare cases, e.g. adding 5.0 + 3.0 or other cases where the mantissa have enough trailing zeros so no `1` bits have to get rounded away after shifting the mantissa to align them).  The number you'd get from doing FP math operations in source order with source-specified precision will have rounding error.

Using multiple accumulators (from vectorizing and unrolling a reduction) is usually *better* numerically, a step in the direction of [pairwise summation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairwise_summation); a simple `sum += a[i]` is the worst way to add an array if the elements are all or mostly positive and of uniform size.  Adding a small number to a large number loses a lot of precision, so having 16 or 32 different buckets to sum into means the totals aren't quite as big until you add the buckets together. See also
*[Simd matmul program gives different numerical results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55477701/simd-matmul-program-gives-different-numerical-results)*.

You can jokingly call this *wrong* because it makes it harder to verify / test that a program does exactly what you think it does, and because it's not what the source says to do.

But unless you're doing stuff like Kahan summation (error-compensation) or double-double (extended precision) or other numerical techniques that depend on precise FP rounding semantics, fast-math optimizations merely give you answers that are wrong in a different way than the source, and mathematically maybe less wrong.

(Unless it also introduces some approximations like `rsqrtps` + a Newton iteration instead of `x / sqrt(y)`.  That may only be on with `fast=2`, which isn't the default.  But I'm not sure.  Some optimizations also might not care about turning `-0.0` into `+0.0`.)

Comment: Intel Fortran also defaults to getting wrong answers quickly.

Comment: @francescalus :) Some might argue a naughty comment. I am assuming you mean it has the annoying default of optimization being turned *on*

Comment: @IanBush: not just optimization on, which is fine and doesn't change results (in correct programs, absent compiler bugs).  But also that it defaults to something similar to GCC's `-ffast-math`, although maybe not quite as aggressive since there are two levels of fast, and the default is only `-fp-model=fast=1`.  Of course, in some cases multiple accumulators give *better* answers than sequentially adding a series of numbers into one `sum += a[i] * b[i]` ; that's the worst way to do it for rounding error if the sequence is uniform and positive.  See updated answer.

Comment: That whitepaper in particular is very informative for those interested to learn more.

Comment: @njuffa: I was mostly focusing on things important for vectorization, like reduction loops.  I think usually using 16 instead of 32 accumulators for example (4 256-bit vectors instead of 4 128-bit vectors) for summing an array or dot-product, for example, won't make a *big* difference, or even vs. a single accumulator unless your data is a specific mix of + / - or different magnitudes.  I could imagine more significant differences from re-associating within an expression if there are variables known to have very different magnitudes; yeah it can matter a lot in some cases.

Comment: Also, the OP reported their results were only slightly different between machines.  Anyway, thanks for the comment, but I think if it's a big deal for your code that's usually because you're intentionally thinking about managing FP rounding error, like I mentioned with Kahan summation or similar techniques.  Otherwise source order might only happen to be good, or might *not* be good.  I think I'm going to leave my answer as it stands; folks who know anything about floating point rounding error should understand the implications, and I don't want to get into the weeds of numerical techniques.